# SSH tunnel connection refused

Tags: linux, ssh, ssh-tunnel

I have a remote machine (IP *XX.XX.XX.XX*) which runs an app written in python/cherrypy which opens a port for http connections on the loopback interface. If I login into the remote machine (using ssh) and then execute

```
curl http://127.0.0.1:8021
```

everything works ok. But, when I set up a tunnel from my local machine using

```
ssh -L 6868:XX.XX.XX.XX:8021 -fN XX.XX.XX.XX
```

and then run

```
curl http://localhost:6868
```

or

```
curl http://127.0.0.1:6868
```

I get this message

```
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

ssh shows this message in the terminal where I created the tunnel

```
channel 2: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
```

For testing, I changed the app to open the port on the real network interface (XX.XX.XX.XX instead of 127.0.0.1) and I used curl from another machine in the same remote network and it worked. Nevertheless, trying to create a tunnel between both remote machines yielded the same results as between a remote server and my local machine.

I've tried to make sure that the problem is not the firewall, so I ran

```
iptables -A INPUT -d 127.0.0.1/32 -i lo -j ACCEPT
```

which I think is enough, but I'm not sure. Here is the ssh -v output

```
[____@YYYY ~]$ ssh -vvL 6868:XX.XX.XX.XX:8021 -fN XX.XX.XX.XX
OpenSSH_5.4p1, OpenSSL 1.0.0-fips 29 Mar 2010
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to [XX.XX.XX.XX] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/____/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/____/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/____/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/____/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.4
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.4 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.4
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0
debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-md5
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-md5
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug2: dh_gen_key: priv key bits set: 117/256
debug2: bits set: 510/1024
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Host 'XX.XX.XX.XX' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/____/.ssh/known_hosts:5
debug2: bits set: 514/1024
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug2: kex_derive_keys
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug2: key: /home/____/.ssh/id_rsa ((nil))
debug2: key: /home/____/.ssh/id_dsa ((nil))
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password,hostbased
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
Credentials cache file '/tmp/krb5cc_524' not found

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
Credentials cache file '/tmp/krb5cc_524' not found

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information


debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/____/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/____/.ssh/id_dsa
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: Next authentication method: password
____@XX.XX.XX.XX's password:
debug2: we sent a password packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentication succeeded (password).
debug1: Local connections to LOCALHOST:6868 forwarded to remote address XX.XX.XX.XX:8021
debug1: Local forwarding listening on ::1 port 6868.
debug2: fd 4 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: channel 0: new [port listener]
debug1: Local forwarding listening on 127.0.0.1 port 6868.
debug2: fd 5 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: channel 1: new [port listener]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: Connection to port 6868 forwarding to XX.XX.XX.XX port 8021 requested.
debug2: fd 6 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug2: fd 6 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: channel 2: new [direct-tcpip]
channel 2: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
debug2: channel 2: zombie
debug2: channel 2: garbage collecting
debug1: channel 2: free: direct-tcpip: listening port 6868 for XX.XX.XX.XX port 8021, connect from 127.0.0.1 port 47048, nchannels 3
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The connection *from your server to XX.XX.XX.XX:8021* is refused.

If a program is configured to listen on the loopback interface, it will **only** answer to connections on the loopback interface's addresses (127.0.0.1 and ::1), **not** on any other addresses the same computer has.

You need to use:

```
ssh -L 6868:127.0.0.1:8021 -fN XX.XX.XX.XX
```

Note that the tunnel target is from the SSH server's perspective.

Comment: How is this different from what the OP tried?

Comment: @AdamSpiers: If a program is only listening on `127.0.0.1`, you can only connect to it at _that specific address_, even when connecting from the same machine.